# Openshift redhat for Windows: rhc command error

Tags: git, rubygems, openshift, openshift-client-tools

I installed ruby and git for Windows as described in the OpenShift [Windows client tools installation guide](https://developers.openshift.com/getting-started/windows.html#client-tools).

When I run an `rhc` command, I get this error:

```
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/user_interaction.rb:328: warning: constant ::TimeoutError is deprecated
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- dl/import (LoadError)
from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/pageant.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/agent/socket.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/agent.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/key_manager.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/ssh_helpers.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/wizard.rb:77:in `<class:Wizard>'
from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/wizard.rb:7:in `<module:RHC>'
from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/wizard.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/commands/base.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/commands/account.rb:2:in `<module:Commands>'
from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/commands/account.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/commands.rb:189:in `block in load'
from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/commands.rb:188:in `each'
from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/commands.rb:188:in `load'
from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/cli.rb:36:in`start'
from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4/bin/rhc:20:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby23/bin/rhc:23:in `load'
from C:/Ruby23/bin/rhc:23:in `<main>'
```

How can I prevent this error and run the OpenShift `rhc` tools in Windows?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rhc setup returns "warning: constant ::TimeoutError is deprecated"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37626020/rhc-setup-returns-warning-constant-timeouterror-is-deprecated)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try uninstalling the current Ruby version and installing [Ruby **1.9.3** for Windows](http://dl.bintray.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/rubyinstaller-1.9.3-p551.exe) which is known to work with rhc tools on Windows.

**EDIT:**
As mentioned in comments below, Ruby **2.0** for Windows is known to work as well.
All archived RubyInstaller versions are available [here](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/archives).

Comment: It's Working, but I would prefer a solution for the last version