# rhc setup returns "warning: constant ::TimeoutError is deprecated"

Tags: ruby, openshift, ubuntu-16.04

**Environment**

- Ubuntu 16.04 xenial
- Linux Kernel: 4.4.0-22-generic
- ruby --version

`ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25) [x86_64-linux-gnu]`

**Steps to replicate**

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-full
rhc setup
```

returns:

> /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/user_interaction.rb:328:
>   warning: constant ::TimeoutError is deprecated

After uploading `default` public key, it shows:

> Checking for git ... found git version 2.7.4
>
> Checking common problems
>   ./var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:67:in
>   `initialize': Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout
>   instead.
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:84:in`
>   initialize': Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout
>   instead. . done

When running:

```
rhc --help
```

It returns:

> /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/user_interaction.rb:328:
>   warning: constant ::TimeoutError is deprecated

Comment: Don't use that version of Ruby.  Try Ruby 2.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a gem uses `Object#timeout` under the hood, which is deprecated. It's recommended to now use `Timeout.timeout`, like the error says.

As far as what you should do - this is just a deprecation *warning*, not an error, so probably nothing is broken.

If the warning is really bothering you, you could edit the gem source at `/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb` and replace the `timeout` calls with `Timeout.timeout` (or fork the gem and make the same changes). The author might appreciate a pull request, if you're eager. But I personally wouldn't worry about this.